# How can I map the print key to take a Skitch for Windows Desktop screenshot on Windows 10?

Tags: autohotkey, hotkeys

Is there any way to configure Skitch for Windows Desktop to take a screenshot when I press the print key on Windows 10? It's okay if I have to use autohotkey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this autohotkey script  to take a fullscreen screenshot:

```
#If ProcessExist("Skitch.exe")

    PrintScreen:: Send {Ctrl Down}{Shift Down}6{Shift Up}{Ctrl Up} ; Ctrl+Shift+6

#If

ProcessExist(name){
    Process, Exist, %name%
    return Errorlevel
}
```